# Is it safe to use shift and @_ in the same statement?

Tags: perl, parameters, shift, unpack

Is the following code *safe*? Does it run on all perl versions >= 5.8? Is it guaranteed that the *shifts* are executed before *@_* is unpacked?

```
sub f1 {
    shift->update(p1 => shift, p2 => shift, @_);
}
```

Verbose alternative code:

```
sub f2 {
    my ($self, $p1, $p2, @r) = @_;
    $self->update(p1 => $p1, p2 => $p2, @r);
}
```

Comment: Unless you're trying to win at golf, do the verbose one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It behaves correctly in all existing Perl interpreters.

However, the operand evaluation order of the comma operator is documented for when it's used in scalar context, but not for when it's used in list context as the case is here. Worse, it's undocumented behaviour in an area that's undefined behaviour in some other languages. I don't see the behaviour changing, but it's not perfectly safe either.

Compromise:

```
sub f3 {
    my $self = shift;
    my $p1   = shift;
    my $p2   = shift;

    $self->update(p1 => $p1, p2 => $p2, @_);
}
```

If you absolutely wanted to go variable-less, you could safely use the following:

```
sub f4 { $_[0]->update(p1 => $_[1], p2 => $_[2], @_[3..$#_]) }
```

I don't know why you'd want to use that, though. It's hard to read even without counting the loss of the self-documenting properties of naming the parameters.

Comment: I only remember perl6 having this explicit undefined behavior to be able to parallelize it, but I don't see any chance that perl5 will ever leave left to right evaluation of argument lists.